# state inside useEffect refers the initial state always with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, immutability, react-hooks

Every time I emit a message from another component, I can't get the full list of messages. Here is the hook and view component:

```
export function useChat() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:3003");
    socket.on("chat message", msg => {
      const newState = update(messages, { $push: [msg] });
      setMessages(newState);
    });
  }, []);

  return { messages };
}
```

Unfortunately the state doesn't persist and shows always the last message:

```
export const HookSockets = () => {
  const { messages } = useChat();
  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map((message, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{message}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If I do this the regular way, everything works as intended:

```
export class ClassSockets extends Component {
  state = {
    socket: openSocket("http://localhost:3003"),
    messages: [],
    message: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.socket.on("chat message", msg => {
      const newState = update(this.state, {
        messages: { $push: [msg] }
      });
      this.setState(newState);
    });
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.state.socket.emit("chat message", this.state.message);
    this.setState({ message: "" });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ message: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Sockets</div>
        <div>{this.state.messages}</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.message}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Send Message</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since you have written your useEffect to execute on initial mount of component, it creates a closure which references the initial value of `messages` and even if the messages update, it will still refer to the same value on subsequent calls

You should instead configure the `useEffect` to run on initial mount and messages change

```
export function useChat() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:3003");
    socket.on("chat message", msg => {
      const newState = update(messages, { $push: [msg] });
      setMessages(newState);
    });
  }, [messages]);

  return { messages };
}
```

or else you could use the callback pattern to update state

```
export function useChat() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:3003");
    socket.on("chat message", msg => {
      setMessages(prevMessages => update(prevMessages, { $push: [msg] }););
    });
  }, []);

  return { messages };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are writing socket handler inside the `useEffect()` with an empty array, So this effect will run only once when your component will mount for the first time. The `socket.on()` function (or closure) will memorize the initial value of the messages and even if the messages gets change the `socket.on()` closure will still refer to its initial value. Solution for this problem will be to register our messages to the dependency array of effect.

```
export function useChat() {   
const [messages, setMessages] = 
useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:3003");
socket.on("chat message", msg => {
  const newState = update(messages, { $push: [msg] });
  setMessages(newState);
});   }, [messages]);
return { messages }; 
}
```

Here a new problem you will encounter that each time messages get changed a new socket with  "chat message" handler is created which may result unexpected and addition code to run multiple times. To solve that issue you will have to de-register the earlier handler. And I'll recommend you to create socket only once (e.g. inside App.js) and pass it as a props.

```
export function useChat(socket) {   
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => { 
socket.on("chat message", msg => {
  const newState = update(messages, { $push: [msg] });
  setMessages(newState);
});   
//De-register old handler   
 return function(){
socket.off("chat message")   } }, [messages]);

return { messages }; }
```