# useState doesn't update its value in React

Tags: reactjs, closures

I want to update **list** came from socket but **setList** doesn't work.
Is it closure thing? then how could i fix it?

```
function List(props) {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.socket) {
      props.socket.on("list", (data) => {
        setList(data);
      });
    }
  }, [props.socket]);

  const renderList = (list) => {
    if (!list) return null;
    

    list.map((room) => {
      return <Room pop={room.length} />;
    });
  };

  return <div>{renderList()}</div>;
}
```

Comment: try to inlcude your list state on the useEffect dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a parameter for your `renderList` function. By doing so, the `list` you're referencing inside it refers to that parameter, rather than the state value. You also aren't returning anything from that function, you don't return the call to `.map`. Try something like this:

```
const renderList = () => {
  if (!list) return null;

  return list.map((room) => <Room pop={room.length} />);
};
```

Also make sure the `props.socket.on(...)` function is actually firing and calling the state update function

EDIT: as others mentioned, check  your dependencies for that `useEffect`. I'm guessing `props.socket` itself doesn't actually ever change, so you can end up with stale data

Answer (score 0):

Yes its a closure thing. Try to include your list state on the useEffect dependency.

see the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54675523/state-inside-useeffect-refers-the-initial-state-always-with-react-hooks) for reference